# Summer '16 Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open

Tags: discussion, mvp

**Public service announcement - Summer '16:**

The [MVP nominations](https://www.salesforce.com/mvp/nominations.jsp) are open from now until June 22, 2016 at 5:00 p.m. PDT.

> The Salesforce MVP program recognizes exceptional individuals in the Salesforce community for their leadership, product knowledge, thought leadership, and ongoing contributions. We induct a new class of Salesforce MVPs two times a year, and it’s time to kick off nominations once again!

Feel free to nominate (or renominate) those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be [users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) or [moderators](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

Comment: can we nominate multiple person?

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes, you can. I'm not aware of a limit. At some point you might be considered a spammer, but you can certainly nominate several people.

Comment: As I understand it, MVP terms last for 1 year (please correct me if this is not correct). How can we find out who's terms are expiring that need to be nominated for an additional term?

Comment: Does a person need to be nominated by multiple persons to have higher chances of being nominated as MVP?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy No.Even a single nomination can make a person MVP .A persons leadership and contribution to community is given higher preference

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. @MohithShrivastava

Comment: @crmprogdev You're correct that knowing who to nominate when could save yourself some time. Either by asking people or finding the latest mvp blog in which they were listed as first time mvp or re-awarded are the only ways I know. me = winter generation.

Comment: @crmprogdev My understanding is that MVPs that are up for renewal will go through a slightly different process and don't necessarily need to be renominated (even though I stated that in the Question :) ). Their contributions to the community with be evaluated again based on the previous years activities. Nominations certainly wouldn't hurt for those in the [Summer '15 group](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/07/welcome-summer-15-class-developer-mvps.html).

Comment: Current MVPs are renewed based on maintained activity (like Daniel says) and feedback from other MVPs.

Comment: I'd say Jon Skeet, but he will win even if he isn't nominated

Comment: Does that mean, one can nominate oneself?  That is still a valid nomination?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy "Anyone can nominate including self nomination" [Source](http://www.slideshare.net/Salesforce/mvp-criteria-nomination-process)